# Using 'offset' in jcarousel - via class name

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I'm trying to set up jcarousel so the thumbnails are *offset* via a class name. Example: A list of twelve thumbnails where the one thumbnail with class="active" is shown as the first visible thumbnail in the jcarousel container.

Comment: not exactly sure what you're trying for, some code might help.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across a few links asking for this same thing. In fact, they may all be posts from you.  Anyhow, I know this is a couple months old at this point, but just in case someone else still needs the info, there appears to be a solution [here](http://cssbeauty.com/skillshare/discussion/3098/tricky-jcarousel-question/).

Good luck!